# ionic 3 typescript error 'ion-footer' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I finished my app build and published it on Android and when I move to ios (I build on VMware) when I run normal ios build it works but I make `build ios --prod` it gives me these errors:

```
   typescript error 
            'ion-icon' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
            this module. 2. If 'ion-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
            '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("-footer class="footer-style-dark"> 
            <ion-toolbar> <ion-title (click)="openAppointment()"> [ERROR ->]<ion-icon class="home"></ion-icon> 
            <span>Book appointment</span></ion-title> </ion-toolbar> </i") 

[17:35:34]  typescript error 
            'ion-title' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
            of this module. 2. If 'ion-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
            '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<ion-footer class="footer-style-dark"> 
            <ion-toolbar> [ERROR ->]<ion-title (click)="openAppointment()"> <ion-icon class="home"></ion-icon> 
            <span>Book appointment</s") 

[17:35:34]  typescript error 
            'ion-toolbar' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is 
            part of this module. 2. If 'ion-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
            '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<ion-footer class="footer-style-dark"> 
            [ERROR ->]<ion-toolbar> <ion-title (click)="openAppointment()"> <ion-icon class="home"></ion-icon> <span") 

[17:35:34]  typescript error 
            'ion-footer' is not a known element: 1. If 'ion-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
            of this module. 2. If 'ion-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the 
            '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<ion-footer 
            class="footer-style-dark"> <ion-toolbar> <ion-title (click)="openAppointment()"") 

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
at /Users/x/Desktop/mybeauty/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (/Users/x/Desktop/mybeauty/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/x/Desktop/mybeauty/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/x/Desktop/mybeauty/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/aot/aot-compiler.js:4:58)
[17:35:34]  copy finished in 23.22 s
```

I have multiple pages. I added on HTML file after `ion-content`. This code

```
<ion-footer >
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title  (click)="openAppointment()" text-center>  <ion-icon name="md-calendar" style="font-size: 25px;"></ion-icon> &nbsp;<span>  order now</span></ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

I searched for solutions I tried many, but doesn't work for me,

- I tried to add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to app.module.ts and all
  page.module.ts

  I tried `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` & `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. I added it and imported it. But it did not work.  The problem is I have deleted that footer from all pages. But it gives me the same error.
- I tried to import ionic module on all page.module.ts.

My app.module.ts  (i used lazy loading and it gives me the same error, I removed all pages.module.ts & import all pages on app.module.ts as below but errors still the same ).
Pages that contain `ion-footer`, are: `ServicepagePages`, `Offerspage`, `Specialist` page.

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {EmailComposer} from '@ionic-native/email-composer';
import { CallNumber } from '@ionic-native/call-number';



import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { AppointmentPage } from '../pages/appointment/appointment';
import { ContactusPage } from '../pages/contactus/contactus';

import { OffersPage } from '../pages/offers/offers';
import { ServicepagePage } from '../pages/servicepage/servicepage';
import { SpecialistPage } from '../pages/specialist/specialist';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { AuthProvider } from '../providers/auth/auth';
import { ClientsProvider } from '../providers/clients/clients';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing';
import { AppRate } from '@ionic-native/app-rate';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    AppointmentPage,
    ContactusPage,
    AboutPage,
    OffersPage,
    ServicepagePage,
    SpecialistPage









  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

  ],schemas:      [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    AppointmentPage,
    ContactusPage,
    AboutPage,
    OffersPage,
    ServicepagePage,
    SpecialistPage



  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    AuthProvider,
    ClientsProvider,
    EmailComposer,
    CallNumber,
    SocialSharing,
    AppRate
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
   CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA;

}
```

Comment: Does your app work with normal build? I mean without doing `--prod` or `--aot`

Comment: What errors do you get when you add the schema's to your `NgModule`? Cause they shouldn't be the same I suppose. Can you post your `app.module.ts`?

Comment: @AmitChigadani thanks for ur reply . normal build i mean : ionic cordova build ios     . i didn't try --aot . or --prod . it build sucessfuly . but once i i build with --prod . it gives me thoese errors

Comment: @Ivaro18 thanks for u're replay , the problem they was the same error .i have added the app.module.ts . and i deleted that ion-footer from all pages and it still gives me that error . Ah the app.module.ts above is the last , i was using lazy loading , i deleted all module.ts files & import all pages on app.module.ts but dosen"t work also .

Comment: @Tomislav I am having the same issues for prod build, how did you solve it?